# Get screen dimensions on Mac OS with .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I get the screen dimensions on Mac OS, using c#? Most of my searches just bring back this:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

However it seems that `Screen` is only for Windows.

Comment: AFAIK .NET Core doesn't have a cross platform way of accessing this information. The Xamarin toolkits might though.

Comment: You can P/Invoke into GLFW which should be able to give you the information.